# Convex analysis problem

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following problem. 
Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously convex. I have to prove that there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}\in \partial f(c)$$
Firstly, I'm being doubt with $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}$ (don't ensure this one is correct, may be it is $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$).
Secondly, I try to prove this problem by using the following proposition $$s\in \partial f(x_0) \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, f(x)\ge f(x_0)+s(x-x_0)$$
That means for this problem, I need to find $c\in (a,b)$ such that
$$f(x)\ge f(c)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-c)$$
or
$$f(x)\ge f(c)+\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a}(x-c)$$
And then, I try to apply the following inequality to this one but cannot.
$$f(x)\le \frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b)$$
So anybody can help me?

Comment: Yes, it must be $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel Fischer. So my direction for this problem is true?

Comment: By continuously convex, do you mean convex and continuous? Because convex functions are always continuous, so that's a bit redundant. Also, it would make more sense if you replace $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ by $\forall x \in [a,b]$, because you cannot apply $f$ on $x$ if $x$ is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva To be picky, a convex function need not be continuous in the endpoints of its domain, if it's defined on a closed interval, so stating the continuity is not redundant here (and essential, consider $f(x) = 0$ for $a \leqslant x < b$, and $f(b) = 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if we mimic the standard proof for the mean value theorem?

Let $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ such that
\begin{equation}
g(t) = f(t) - M(t - a)
\end{equation}
where $M$ is chosen so that $g(b) = f(a)$.
Note that $g$ is convex and continuous and $g(a) = g(b)$.
Hence $g$ has a minimizer $c \in (a,b)$.
It follows that
\begin{equation}
0 \in \partial g(c) = \partial f(c) - M
\end{equation}
or in other words
\begin{equation}
M \in \partial f(c).
\end{equation}

Now $g(b) = f(a)$ gives us
\begin{align}
&f(b) = f(a) + M(b-a) \\
\implies &\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = M \in \partial f(c)
\end{align}
which is what we wanted.

Comment: I wonder why $\partial g(c)=\partial f(x)-M$ since I see that $\partial g(c)=\left\{s\in \mathbb{R}| sd\le f'(c,d)-Md,\forall d\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

Comment: The function $h(t) = -M(t-a)$ is convex and differentiable, and a theorem from convex analysis tells us that $\partial (f + h)(c) = \partial f(c) + h'(c)$.  This result is very plausible, but I think the proof requires some care.  Assuming this result and noting that $h'(c) = -M$, we obtain $\partial g(c) = \partial f(c) - M$.

Comment: I see it is not plausible at all. Could you give me  the detail proof for this theorem?

Comment: Well, in ordinary calculus we have the rule that $(f + h)'(c) = f'(c) + h'(c)$ (assuming $f$ and $h$ are differentiable at $c$).  In convex analysis our functions may not be differentiable, and the subdifferential is like a substitue for the derivative.  We may guess that a similar rule holds true: $\partial (f + h)(c) = \partial f(c) + \partial h(c)$.  Indeed this holds under mild conditions on $f$ and $h$, I'll try to find a reference for a theorem/proof.  Moreover if $h$ is differentiable at $c$ then $\partial h(c) = \{ h'(c) \}$, which is another standard result from convex analysis.

Comment: Sorry it's just because I want everything to be clear. I knew what you mean, but I have never seen this equality. I just knew this one: $\partial (f+g)(x)\supset \partial f(x)+\partial g(x)$.

Comment: I've just seen a theorem associated with its proof: Let $f,g$ be proper convex function on $E$ and if there is a point in $dom(f)\cap dom(g)$ where $f$ is continuous then $\partial (f+g)(x)=\partial f(x)+\partial g(x), \forall x\in E.$
So I think I can try to consider this condition for my problem. :)